# What is wrong with the syntax in this MYSQL query?

Tags: mysql, function, replace, syntax

I am trying to replace all the 'abc' in column1 with blanks but received this error. Help will be appreciated!

```
SELECT * 
REPLACE(column1, 'abc', '') 
FROM database.table;
```

Comment: If you insist on not using backticks, don't name your table `table`.

Comment: What was the error? I can see at least three problems with the query. No comma after *, no backticks on database, no backticks on table.

Comment: Thank you!! It was the 'no comma after *'. I didn't realize you needed to put commas after the select statement in general.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming reserved words are only illustrative then following should work [ref](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php):

```
SELECT *, REPLACE(column1,'abc','') FROM database.table;
```

As @Sloan Thrasher observed you have missed a comma to separate the columns. If the reserved words really are used you need to put them in backticks or you will get a syntax error [see SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql). So the query would become:

```
SELECT *, REPLACE(column1,'abc','') FROM `database`.`table`;
```

Comment: The dot takes care of the reserved words

Comment: @Strawberry that makes sense. Can't say I would consider using reserved words in my schema, just in case.

Comment: Fair dos. I wouldn't either ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

UPDATE database.table 
   SET column1 = REPLACE(column1, 'abc', '');

Comment: this assumes he wants to update the data in column1 where the question suggests he justs wants to change the output from the select query. Using this syntax could damage his data if it was not what he intended.